# Knowing which characteristics a given central has subscribed with CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I have a service with several characteristics which is being advertised using Bluetooth LE. I do not want to start sending data to a central until it has subscribed all four characteristics, but I can't seem to find a way to know which characteristics have been subscribed. This obviously forces me to manually keep track of which characteristics have been subscribed so far, but, if possible, I'd like to avoid that. Is there a way to list characteristics subscribe by a given central?

Comment: I think that the central would (reasonably) expect that it will get data from each characteristic as soon as it subscribes to it. I'm not sure if the behaviour you are trying to implement is consistent with Bluetooth Low Energy spec.

Comment: I guess that's true. Nevertheless I need that behaviour. I guess I'll keep track of subscribed characteristics manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property called `subscribedCentrals` in [CBMutableCharacteristic](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBMutableCharacteristic_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CBMutableCharacteristic/subscribedCentrals). You can use it for your purposes - each time a central subscribes to a characteristic, you can check if it's  already subcribed to the other characteristics (probably you store a list of `CBMutableCharacteristic` instances somewhere, so you can iterate over them).

As I've previously mentioned in my comment, it might not be a good idea if you want to be a good citizen of the world of Bluetooth Low Energy. A developer of a central connecting to tour peripheral might be confused when he or she doesn't get updates notifications from the characteristic which he or she's subscribed to.

As soon as you are in full control of the central (e.g. you develop both the peripheral and the central which are used only in your app), it's not a problem. Otherwise I would suggest re-thinking your approach, maybe there's another solution which will work for you and the other developers which would like to use your BLE service.

Comment: I don't even know how I missed that! I understand that this approach is not according to BLE specification or purpose, but in this specific case it makes sense and that's what I need. Thank you for your remarks!